# Swift and Cocoapods - Missing required module

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I am trying to make a Swift framework. This framework depends on two libraries, [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) and [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON), which are both written in Swift.

I am using CocoaPods to import these libraries in my framework. Here is the content of my Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '1.2'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '2.2'
```

In my framework, I have a class that imports and uses these two modules:

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
```

I can run `pod install` and **build my framework successfully**!

Now things get tricky when I'm trying to use my framework in a Swift project.

1. I copy the `.framework` file into my project.
2. In the Build Phases of my project's target, I add a Copy Files Phase with "Destination" set to "Frameworks", and add my framework file.

[image: Copy Frameworks Build Phase]

3. I import my framework in a Swift class of my project:

   ```
   import MyFramework
   ```

The problem is: Xcode keeps telling me

> Missing required module 'SwiftyJSON'

And more surprising: if I don't use SwiftyJSON and remove it from my framework (but still use Alamofire)... **It works!** And I have the same problem with any other lib than SwiftyJSON. Only Alamofire seems to work.

I've already seen some issues, like [this one](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3095), and tried some things (changing Build Settings, adding the libraries to the Linked Libraries, adding a Bridging Header though I'm not dealing with ObjC) with no effect...

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this problem? It's driving me nuts!

EDIT: I'm using Cocoapods v0.37.0.beta.1. Same issue with v0.36.4.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved after updating Xcode to version 6.3.1.