# Error: "no such module <Swift Cocoapod name>" with Jenkins

Tags: swift, jenkins, cocoapods, xcodebuild

I'm trying to setup **Jenkins** slave, to build my Swift project that uses a Swift pod called "Freddy".

The problem is the build failed with error:

> error: no such module 'Freddy'

This is my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyProject' do

pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
pod 'Freddy'

end
```

CocoaPods version 0.39.0

Xcode 7.2.1 (**no problems while building from Xcode directly**)

PS. Same problem had happened with Alamofire pod before I replaced it with AFNetworking.

PSS. Jenkins executes following xcodebuild:

`xcodebuild -scheme MyProject -workspace MyProject.xcworkspace -configuration Debug clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=jenkinsOutput "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=iPhone Developer: Andrei Kadochnikov (XXXXXXXX)" -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=latest"`

PSSS. **I've tried to execute this command from terminal by myself, got same error as Jenkins shows me.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift and Cocoapods - Missing required module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829641/swift-and-cocoapods-missing-required-module)

Comment: @techloverr 1. I'm on XCode 7.2.1. 
2. The error text is different.

Comment: @techloverr 3. I'm not building from XCode directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured that the build was failed because of parameter  `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=jenkinsOutput`. I've got rid of it and build succeeded.
Confusing error message.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Where did you find this CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=jenkinsOutput . and did you deleted it?

Comment: @Khushabu CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR is a setting defining where the prepared build file will be put in. Yes I deleted this setting in favor of default setting. This allowed my build to run successfully.

Comment: @Khushabu another option is to specify some meaningful path, for example `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/bobthebuilder/Jenkins/Workspace/build`

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this error recently，`"no such module"` and I finally  found it course by the `xcodebuild` is a project not workspace.

Check the advanced settings on xcode plugin set the workspace path.

That solved the problem.

Comment: When I specify workspace path, I get error to specify scheme settings too. What you have done exactly? can you please elaborate step by step?