# xCode Project: Jenkins "No Such Module"

Tags: swift, xcode, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have created an xCode project that uses Carthage to manage libraries and everything works in xCode but when I start a build in Jenkins I get the error "No Such Module". The build is configured to work with the .xcworkspace pointing to the correct app schema. **Similar question on Stackoverflow** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868257/error-no-such-module-swift-cocoapod-name-with-jenkins). This is not the issue for me because my build is configured to use xcworkspace. For more clarity I used these steps [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/165660/carthage-tutorial-getting-started-2) when setting up Carthage.

Below is the console output: 
[image]

Comment: have you solved this issue?

Comment: @Dari Added carthage bootstrap --platform iOS as an Execute Shell in the build section of my configuration